# Webview Load to touch

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

Hello Im New in Xcode Development and i try to make a Easy app
My App:
my mobile app have 5 Tabs, All the tabs have Webview and the problem is to load the app,
Everything works very slow.
I have seen some applications when changing tab load the Webview.
anyone can help me with this.

Sorry for my English i use Google translate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1744203 I can get u now. You can call all the Tab actions in MainViewController then all the actions will be loaded then this reduces the loading time.Still having problem then you can use jQuery which traverse HTML documents speedly...

Maybe this [click on this link can help you in fixing jQuery](http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uiwebview/load-jquery-in-uiwebview/)

Hope this Helps!!!!